# Network Configuration: systemd-networkd vs networking,service, and compatiblity with ip command

Tags: linux, networking, debian, systemd

I am trying to connect an IOT device running Debian to the Wifi, and in doing so, I'm trying to configure a wlan0 interface. I've noticed there are a few ways to do this. FROM WHAT I UNDERSTAND (which may well be wrong):

1) there seems to be a systemd-networkd way, which involves modifying a  `/etc/systemd/network/wlan0.network` file, and then ideally `systemd-networkd.service` sets up the interfaces at boot.

2) there is the classical `ifupdown` configuration way, which mainly relies on the `/etc/networking/interfaces` file for configuration. Then, the networking service `networking.service` sets up these services at boot.

My questions are 1) am I correct in how they work, 2) should you only have one of these services enabled at any given time, and 3) once everything is setup, are they both compatible with the `ip/ifconfig` commands, and the `ifup` and `ifdown` commands?

Basically, if someone could give me an overview of how these services and interfaces interact, what's legacy and what's not, etc, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) am I correct in how they work

Yes, although ifupdown prefers `ifup@<interface>.service` now.

> 2) should you only have one of these services enabled at any given time

Generally yes, but the important bit is that only one service should manage *an interface* at any given time. It is quite possible (but probably not recommended) to use different services for different interfaces, e.g. use systemd-networkd for setting up tunnels while still using ifupdown to set up Ethernet.

(For example, I use NetworkManager for my general PC networking, but also have systemd-networkd to create WireGuard links, a "virtual machines" bridge, and such.)

> 3) once everything is setup, are they both compatible with the ip/ifconfig commands

`ip` – yes.

`ifconfig` – partially. Among other problems it has, this tool is incapable of showing multiple IPv4 addresses per interface (unless they're labelled with legacy "aliases"). This is not actually an incompatibility of networkd and ifconfig specifically; rather it's an incompatibility of modern Linux IP stack and ifconfig.

> 3) once everything is setup, are they both compatible with [...] the ifup and ifdown commands?

The `ifup/ifdown` commands are exactly the same "ifupdown" which you mentioned.  You could say that networking.service just runs `ifup <name>` for every interface listed as 'auto'. (It's a common misconception that they're low-level tools, or abbreviations for `ifconfig up`, but they are not.)

Therefore, only interfaces listed in /etc/network/interfaces are compatible with ifup/ifdown.

Comment: Thank you!!! This is very helpful